# VB DownloadFile URL variable

Tags: vb.net, download

I'm attempting to pass a string to the DownloadFile function in Visual Basic in place of the URL. The url will change according to what the current month and year is. Ex: http://example-website.com/092015

For this reason, I've done the following to make sure the url is updated every month:

```
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim A As String = "http://example-website.com/"
        Dim B As String = Format(Month(Now), "00")
        Dim C As String = Year(Now)
        Dim registrySite As String = A & B & C
    End Sub
```

The problem that I'm having is, the DownloadFile function requires a string.

```
Public Sub DownloadFile (
    address As String,
    destinationFileName As String
)
```

Is there a workaround for this or another way to do what I'm trying to do? I should note that the website cannot be cached.

Comment: I dont understand the problem: you created a a string, and it takes a string.  The date portion is incorrect though for the example given and easier to do.

Comment: just use `Dim registrySite As String = "http://example-website.com/" & String.Format("{0:MMyyyy}", Date.Now)` or `Dim registrySite As String = "http://example-website.com/" & Date.Now.ToString("MMyyyy")` ... result is same. `MM` is for month format, eg. 01 or 08, ... and `yyyy` for year format.

Comment: nelek, great suggestion. Thanks.